# Access denied (403) for PHP files with Nginx + PHP-FPM

Tags: nginx, permissions, fedora, php, http-status-code-403

I have been spending few hours on that issue and despite the high number of posts related to it, I cannot solve it. I have a Fedora 20 box with Nginx + PHP-FPM that worked quite good until today (after I reloaded php-fpm.service I guess). Nginx is serving static files with no problem, but any PHP file triggers an error 403.

The permissions are ok, nginx and php-fpm are running under the user "nginx":

```
root     13763  0.0  0.6 490428 24924 ?        Ss   15:47   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php-fpm.conf)
nginx    13764  0.0  0.1 490428  7296 ?        S    15:47   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    13765  0.0  0.1 490428  7296 ?        S    15:47   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    13766  0.0  0.1 490428  7296 ?        S    15:47   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    13767  0.0  0.1 490428  7296 ?        S    15:47   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
nginx    13768  0.0  0.1 490428  6848 ?        S    15:47   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

The served files have been set to nginx user as well, I even ended chmoding 777 those files to try, but still "Access denied" for any PHP files.

Below is a server of my Nginx config:

```
server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     localhost;

        root            /var/www/html;

         location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

The PHP-FPM pool:

```
[www]
...
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
user = nginx
group = nginx
...
```

For the versions:

**php-5.5.11** (as well as **php-fpm-5.5.11** of course)

**nginx-1.4.7**

I am adding the Nginx error log:

```
 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/var/www/html' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
```

And precise that `security.limit_extensions` is correct, set to: `security.limit_extensions = .php`.

About the path permissions, **/var/www/html** can be traversed.
What am I missing?

Comment: I know it sounds weird, but did you double check whether you have edited the right php.ini file regarding to limit_extensions? I made this mistake the other day..

Comment: `limit_extensions` is present only in the FPM pool, for me with Fedora 20 in `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`.. But thank you John

Comment: have you tried setting the `fastcgi_pass` to the socket address instead of the serveraddress (e.g. unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;)?

Comment: Yes I tried this too, but the result is the same. I'm running out of ideas with this issue..

Comment: Well.. could you set the `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME` to `$fastcgi_script_name`, reload fpm and try again? Without `$document_root`...

Comment: The same problem John, thx

Comment: Yeah it's kinda embarrassing but I had this problem two weeks ago and I didn't write down how I solved it, of course.. Anyway, here's my last idea and I kinda think that was the thing: Remove everything from the `security.limit_extensions` so it looks like this: `security.limit_extensions = `..

Comment: I tried too ;] But without success. Then I get a 404 even if the file exists. Error log:

`FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/html (Success)" while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock:", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"`

Some thread suggested to set it to FALSE too, same result.

Comment: Huh.. I think that we're heading in the right direction ;) please keep the `limit_extensions` empty and include `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;`in your location block and try again with and without the $doc_root in `SCRIPT_FILENAME`

Comment: try this: `location ~ \.php$ {

include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;}`

Comment: John, I found a solution and I feel stupid about it. In the php.ini, I switched the `cgi.fix_pathinfo` from 0 to 1 and everything is working now. Thank you for your time, you support helped! ;]

Comment: Great! I'm gonna answer with all the possible solutions for future reference.. You don't have to accept it, of course!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here are some possible solutions:

1. In your php-fpm www.conf set `security.limit_extensions` to `.php` or `.php5` or whatever suits your environment. For some users, completely removing all values or setting it to `FALSE` was the only way to get it working.
2. In your nginx config file set `fastcgi_pass` to your socket address (e.g. `unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;`) instead of your server address and port.
3. Check your `SCRIPT_FILENAME` fastcgi param and set it according to the location of your files.
4. In your nginx config file include `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;` in the location block where all the other fastcgi params are defined.
5. In your php.ini set `cgi.fix_pathinfo` to `1`

Comment: Are you sure is safe to set fix_pathinfo to 1 ? Check http://serverfault.com/questions/627903/is-the-php-option-cgi-fix-pathinfo-really-dangerous-with-nginx-php-fpm

Comment: If #1 and #4 are implemented, it's perfectly safe to implement #5. Actually... #1 and #5 were defaulted to `.php` and `1` respectively in PHP 5.5.

Comment: I was trying to get .html files to run as .php files, so #1 above with "sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm" did it for me.   Cheers.

Comment: Guys its not safe. In NGINX oficial website it says it opens a security hole that allows to upload something.

Comment: when i change ```cgi.fix_pathinfo``` to 1, site works well.

Answer (score 10):

Please note that the above solution (set `cgi.fix_pathinfo` to `1`) is a *terrible* idea. See https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/ for a good overview.

The issue is probably down to your application relying on PATH_INFO. Enable access logging for php to get more information about how your application is called to help you debug this issue.

Once again, just to be sure - the accepted solution is a *terrible* idea, and will likely get your site hacked.

Comment: It's not a terrible idea and it won't get your site hacked. It's the default value for PHP 5.5. If you pass to PHP-FPM as instructed here you're fine: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/#connecting-nginx-to-php-fpm

Answer (score 3):

Do not forget to restart php5-fpm service after changing php.ini!!

service php5-fpm restart
or
service php5-fpm reload

fpm prestarts php5 so it is not enough to restart nginx to have the changes applied.

Answer (score 1):

It may be related to **selinux**. If you use the **shared folder** of **Virtual Box**, you cannot change the access permissions in this folder in Linux. Therefore, you can solve it after closing **selinux**.

Answer (score 0):

For reference of those coming later:
In the conf for your site try to add:
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
Also look at what SELinux is doing. To turn it off: setenforce 0
But then figure what script is the issue and put back to setenforce 1

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen if there is no `index.php` in your vhost document root.

Carefully double-check the `www_root` parameter in your nginx configuration. Then double check that the php file you're trying to hit is actually in there.

In my case, I mis-typed the vhost doc root path and so pointed it to an empty directory, yielding a 403.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and after trying all the suggestions above it still didn't work. Then I checked my files. Obviously I am not a server expert.

It turned out I have a folder /sites-available and /sites-enabled.
I had updated the default file in the sites-available folder but not in the /sites-enabled folder. After doing that (and a restart of nginx), it all started to work.

Took me some time to solve this, I hope this helps someone else to fix it sooner.