# Contents are not served with "Access denied" error in Nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, webserver, php

I'm getting a `Access denied` message any time I try to access the WebServer through `http://dev` or `http://devserver` address. I don't know what is wrong on my Nginx config. Below is the `config.php` and `default` site configuration:

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

   ## Load virtual host conf files. ##
   include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

This file has a symbolic link to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` so it's enabled:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {
    listen 80 default;
    listen [::]:80 default ipv6only=on;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/ or server IP-address
    server_name dev devserver;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

    charset utf-8;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then trigger 404
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

        # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_index index.php;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html;

        # send bad requests to 404
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I'm on CentOS 6.6 with Nginx 1.6.2 and PHP 5.5.18 with PHP-FPM. Also I have SELinux disabled and the only thing I have there is Iptables. Other sites runs fine and by sites I mean any that points to the `root` directory, for example this one which is a Symfony2 project:

```
server {
    server_name newsite.dev newsite.webvm newsite;
    root /var/www/html/newsite.dev/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/newsite.dev/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/newsite.dev/error.log;
}
```

In that case calling `http://newsite.dev` or `http://newsite.webvm` or `http://newsite` I get the expected result, the site but the first is not working and I do not know what else to do, so any help or advice around the configuration and why contents are not served?

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions and owner groups? Also check your error log it should have more info.

Comment: @Kypros permissions of which directory? Take a look to this: `
drwxr-xr-x 3 apache root 4096 Oct 31 08:25 october.dev
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root   22 Oct 29 10:12 phpMyAdmin -> /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/ drwxr-xr-x 8 apache root 4096 Oct 28 17:06 newsite.dev` I can reach `newsite.dev` but `dev/phpMyAdmin` or `dev/october.dev` trhow `Access denied` and this is what logs says `[error] 9237#0: *922 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/var/www/html/october.dev' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream`, any advice?

Comment: Try the solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390531/access-denied-403-for-php-files-with-nginx-php-fpm

Comment: @Kypros I tried all in the answer of that post, is not working

Comment: That `drwxr-xr-x 3 apache root 4096`  looks odd since you are using nginx. Try `sudo chown -R YOUR_USER:nginx /var/www/html/october.dev` since it should be `www-data` or `nginx` for you since you are specifying `user nginx` in `nginx.conf`